# Can't boot Ubuntu 18.04 from USB while running 22.04

Tags: boot, usb

I keep reading the forum posts about my question but I still can't install or run 18.04.  The computer in question is old (from 2007) with a Core 2 Duo 2.2GHz and 2 Gb of DDR-2 RAM.  I have Jammy Jellyfish 22.04 running on it now.  It had come with Windows Vista.  I have set the BIOS to boot from USB first.  I used 22.04 for a month now and it is just too slow on my ancient hardware.  I want to downgrade to 18.04 for a better and more stable experience, but I cannot get booted into 18.04 on the USB stick.  It goes past the flash drive momentarily and boots from the hard drive which has 22.04 on it.
There are 3 boot options in the BIOS and I have even tried setting all 3 of them to USB, thinking that the machine would not boot 22.04 from the hard drive, but it does anyway.  The machine does not seem to follow what the BIOS is set for.  I do save the BIOS settings and see that they remain there.  I usually have boot #1 set to USB, #2 set to DVD, and #3 set to the HDD.
I have even removed all the other USB devices (keyboard, mouse, and WiFi dongle) but although the flash drive was polled briefly it did not begin the installation and the hard disk started 22.04.
I have used both Etcher and Rufus to prepare the flash drive.  Somehow I did manage to install 22.04 from the flash drive, so it has worked at least once before.  I am at a standstill.  Thanks for any help and consideration.  I have learned a lot from this forum.

Comment: *I want to downgrade to 18.04 for a better and more stable experience* You won't get it and 18.04 have less than one year of support left. What may improve the experience is (1) HARDWARE > An SSD and more RAM, if supported; (2) DON'T use standard Ubuntu, prefer a flavor with a lighter Desktop Environment like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: The above of course has nothing to do with the ability or lack thereof of booting installation media. That was wrongly made, that's all. In order to follow advice #2 above you WILL need to make a proper USB installation/live media anyway.